# Suggestions for a non-traditional interview?

Tags: postdocs, interview

I will have a post-doc interview in social sciences, warned to be a bit nontraditional in the sense that it will focus more on general logical capabilities and unique/creative thoughts instead of specific sets of skill or fit with a particular project. The reason is because this is a training grant I guess. Literally, they want to emphasize on "innovative" aspects of applicants, though I think that it's quite tempting and ambiguous.

So, I guess that I'd want to ask for questions you may have that can train the brain in this direction, some thing thought-intriguing like this:

- What is the most significant finding in your field in the last couple of years and how does that mean to your specific work?

Any comments are welcome :) Btw, if you happen to be in social sciences, how would you answer the above question?

Comment: "warned to be a bit nontraditional in the sense that it will focus more on general logical capabilities and unique/creative thoughts instead of specific sets of skill or fit with a particular project."  It sounds like you are well aware that that could mean almost anything (or nothing: it could mean that they'll just pick whoever they like and don't want to be held accountable for why).  Did they really tell you this in such slippery, nebulous language?  Also, something seems conspicuously missing from the quoted dichotomy: **won't they ask about your thesis work??**

Comment: Also, your sample question doesn't seem nearly as spacey as what is presented in the first paragraph.  I can't say that it is a standard postdoc interview question in my field (e.g. because it is not standard to do interviews for postdocs in my field) but it sounds more than reasonable.  I wonder though how some other social scientist's answer to that question would help *you* out?

Comment: Well, they didn't literally say it could be "anything", but instead informed that the interview will mostly cover general questions.

Comment: I find myself scratching my head that someone could be looking for a postdoc who is an "innovative thinker" and would not try to ascertain this by talking to the candidate about what they've been thinking about and working on for their thesis.  I would think that would be the best way to get innovative thinkers -- much better than asking some weirdo on-the-spot question and watching in what manner the candidates squirms.  What do you make of this?

Comment: (This should attach to the previous comment, but it passes the allowed time) In the announcement, they want to find postdocs who can contribute to move the field forward in big leaps, not "baby" steps. I think it's more a product of marketing to secure training funds though. About the question, I just learn that you're in maths. I'm not sure whether mathematicians can keep updated with most advanced breakthroughs in the field, but in applied social sciences it's hard to tell whether some work is the most influential, especially in a short period.

Comment: Your last comment tells quite exactly about the atypical nature of this interview. A simple proof, there will be 3-4 interviewers and the interview will last only about 15 minutes! I don't think I can present half of my work and future directions in this time frame. Somehow it feels like how I respond is more important than what I respond. There's some chance to talk about the dissertation, but I believe it will not be into details as much.

Comment: Wait, what? The whole interview is only 15 minutes?!?  Is this an on-campus interview, or something that takes place at a big conference or somesuch?  In mathematics we use the term "cattle call" for the latter and generally acknowledge that such interviews need not amount to much.  It is hard for me to believe that anyone who has seriously narrowed down the pool to a small number of contenders would be willing to spare so little time interviewing them.  I am tenured so be careful listening to what I say, but: I think I would not have been so keen on this type of interview.

Comment: (To answer your other question: in mathematics there is a very small percentage of top work that everyone agrees right away will be huge: e.g. solutions of hundred year old problems and the like.  The average graduating PhD is not likely to be up on such earth-shattering things beyond the level of gossip/broad culture though.  I took the question to be more localized -- i.e., not field like "mathematics" but sub-subfield that the graduating student is working in -- and also more subjective -- i.e., tell us what is important *to you*.  I actually like this as an interview question!)

Comment: Yes, that's right. It's an on-campus, 15-minute interview. It looks like I will be toasted for a quarter of hour by 4 interviewers, who, by reading their bios, don't have reasonable levels of expertise on what I'm doing. This further enforces my thought that the interview will be different from otherwise normal ones. I wouldn't be keen on this formation either, but I've taken it since I know that, once in, postdocs have great opportunities to collaborate and develop career paths. It's hard to tell though whether previous cohorts of postdocs here have really done "innovative" scholastic works.

Comment: Well, you seem to have a realistic take on it then.  Best of luck: sorry I can't be of any real help.

Comment: 15 minutes, on campus??!! *boggle* I hope at least it's local.  I can't imagine getting on a plane for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without more information, I would not assume that they will not ask you about your research, publications, and dissertation.  Assume that they will.  My impression is that they want to go beyond this "CV stuff".

I suggest that you should spend more time to understand the motivations of the organization sponsoring the post-doc and why this is funded as a training grant rather than as something else.  Do they put special emphasis on making their research relevant to the real world (i.e. to policy makers, to the social groups being studied, to the general public)?  Do they aim to develop social scientists that go into non-traditional careers or interdisciplinary work?  What has this organization done in the past that they themselves call "innovative"?  Do they aim to redefine the boundaries and methods of social science?

---

Regarding how to prepare, there are plenty of books on creativity that have exercises that might stimulate this part of your brain.  But I'd guess that spending time on these books won't provide a good payoff for you.

A better strategy would be to organize a debating group with some peers.  They don't have to be at your university.  You could do it on-line via Skype or Google Hangout.  Arrange a meeting and specify an important+controversial topic in your field.  Focus the debate on how this topic could be researched in a new and different way, such that breakthrough results might be achieved.  For example:

- Could the problem be reframed, rescoped, or redefined?
- Could new methods be applied or existing methods be combined?
- What new methods/approaches have already been tried but have failed? Why?
- What methods or approaches from other disciplines might be adapted or applied to this topic?
- What if this topic was researched at a much larger scale? much smaller scale? Over a long time period? At a single moment in time but in great detail?
- How can research results become more compelling, rigorous, or widely applicable?

And so on.

Basically, your debating group will be exploring the space of possibilities just beyond what is being done today and assessing the prospects of improvement or innovation.

The value of doing this in a group rather than solo is that you will be engaging in the same modes of thinking and communication as the interview. You can and should challenge each other to clearly explain and justify your ideas, and to properly characterize them even if they are sketchy or "wacky".

You might find that this sort of preparation isn't for you.  If so, then maybe you might have to admit to yourself that you aren't an "innovator".  That's fine. There are many other good roles in social science that emphasize other traits and skills.